# can`t find "cpu.cfs_period_us" and "cpu.cfs_quota_us" in cgroup

Tags: linux, docker, linux-kernel, cgroups

I want to limit the CPU usage of the process through CGroup.After searching for some information on the Internet, I learned that it needed to be revised  "cpu.cfs_period_us" and "cpu.cfs_quota_us",but now I can`t find these two files in cgroup.

**My steps are as follows**

The path "/sys/fs/cgroup" already exists in my Linux system, but there are no files in it.So I mount the cgroup/cpu/ file according to the reference standard steps:

```
cd /sys/fs/
mount -t tmpfs cgroup_root ./cgroup
mkdir cgroup/cpu
mount -t cgroup -ocpu cpu ./cgroup/cpu/
```

What puzzles me is that my ./cgroup/cpu/ directory doesn't have "cpu.cfs_period_us" and "cpu.cfs_quota_us"...   What's the reason? Is it a kernel configuration problem?
I have these files in my ./cgroup/cpu path:

```
/sys/fs # ls ./cgroup/cpu/
cgroup.clone_children  cpu.rt_period_us       release_agent
cgroup.procs           cpu.rt_runtime_us      tasks
cgroup.sane_behavior   haoel
cpu.notify_on_migrate  notify_on_release
```

**Other information**

1)my linux system info

```
/ # cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.18.20 (gcc version 4.9.2 (GCC) ) #1 PREEMPT Tue Mar 9 03:52:45 CST 2021

/ # uname -a
Linux mdm9607-perf 3.18.20 #1 PREEMPT Tue Mar 9 03:52:45 CST 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

2)Related kernel configuration

```
CONFIG_CGROUPS=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_DEBUG=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_FREEZER=y
# CONFIG_CGROUP_DEVICE is not set
# CONFIG_CPUSETS is not set
CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT=y
CONFIG_RESOURCE_COUNTERS=y
# CONFIG_MEMCG is not set
# CONFIG_CGROUP_PERF is not set
CONFIG_CGROUP_SCHED=y
# CONFIG_FAIR_GROUP_SCHED is not set
CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED=y
# CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP is not set
```

Comment: Your kernel version is old: stabilized in 2014 (and so no new features, just fixes)

Comment: Hi Catenazzi, thx for your help! Could you pls tell me how  to find this information? Is there a linux official document or kernel update log?

Comment: This feature dates from 2011 and exists in 3.18, but needs `CONFIG_CFS_BANDWIDTH=y`.

Comment: Thank you Abbott, I’ll try it.

Comment: Note that `CONFIG_CFS_BANDWIDTH=y` also depends on `CONFIG_FAIR_GROUP_SCHED=y`.

Comment: Hi Abbott, 
Your answer helped me solve this problem. Thank you very much!!